# how to play audio file on each question on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

var questions = [];
var images = {}
So, the inside of "questions" array have another array that can call "images" array the problem here is how to call the "audio array" i have made an array for the audio but it seems not working
var sounds ={}

I have also tried another method which is putting html element inside of the array of variables but still, it's not working

HTML css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Picture Quiz</title>
      <style>
         body {
         background-color: #eeeeee;
         }
         .grid {
         width: 68%;
         height: 520px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         background-color: #fff;
         padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
         border-radius: 50px;
         border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
         box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
         }
         .buttons img
         {
         width:200px;
         }
         .grid h1 {
         font-family: "sans-serif";
         background-color: #ffc107;
         font-size: 35px;
         text-align: center;
         color: #ffffff;
         padding: 2px 0px;
         border-radius: 50px;
         }
         hr
         {
         margin-top: 50px;
         color: red;
         background-color: #ffc107;
         height: 2px;
         border: none;
         }
         #score {
         color: #ffc107;
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 30px;
         }
         .grid #question {
         font-family: "monospace";
         font-size: 30px;
         color: #ffc107;
         }
         .buttons {
         margin-top: 30px;
         }
         #btn0,
         #btn1,
         #btn2,
         #btn3 {
         padding: 0px;
         font-size: 20px;
         color: #fff;
         border: none;
         margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
         }
         #btn0:hover,
         #btn1:hover,
         #btn2:hover,
         #btn3:hover {
         cursor: pointer;
         background-color: #ffc107;
         }
         #btn0:focus,
         #btn1:focus,
         #btn2:focus,
         #btn3:focus {
         outline: 0;
         }
         #progress {
         color: #2b2b2b;
         font-size: 18px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="grid">
         <div id="quiz">
            <h1>Picture Quiz</h1>
            <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">
            <p id="question"></p>
            <p id="audio"></p>
            <div class="buttons">
               <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
               <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
               <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
               <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
               <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
            </footer>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var images = {
"dog": "dog.jpg",
"cow": "cow.jpg",
"cat": "cat.jpg",
"goat": "goat.jpg",
"deer": "deer.jpg",
"hen": "hen.jpg",
"lion": "lion.jpg",
"parrot": "parrot.jpg",
"tiger": "tiger.jpg"

}  

var sounds = {
    "audio1" : "grizz.mp3",
    "audio2" : "immortal.mp3",
    "audio3" : "genshoshi.mp3",
    "audio4" : "genshoshi.mp3",
    "audio5" : "immortal.mp3"

}

function populate() {
if (quiz.isEnded()) {
showScores();
} else {
// show question
var element = document.getElementById("question");
element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

// show audio
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().audio;



// show options
var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
element.innerHTML = images[choices[i]]? '<img src="'+images[choices[i]]+'"/>':choices[i];
guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);


}

showProgress();
}
};


function guess(id, guess) {
var button = document.getElementById(id);
button.onclick = function() {
quiz.guess(guess);
populate();
}
};

function showProgress() {
var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
var element = document.getElementById("progress");
element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function showScores() {
var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

// create questions
var questions = [
new Question(["Which one is dog?"],"audio1",["cow", "goat", "cat", "dog"], "dog"),
new Question(["select tiger below"],"audio2",["parrot", "deer", "tiger", "lion"], "tiger"),
new Question(["choose parrot pls?"],"audio3",["hen", "parrot", "goat",  "dog"], "parrot"),
new Question(["Find cat below?"],"audio4",["parrot", "goat", "cat", "tiger"], "cat"),
new Question(["choose lion pls?"],"audio5",["lion", "goat", "tiger", "dog"], "lion")
];

questions.sort(function(){
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

function Question(text, audio , choices, answer) {
this.text = text;
this.audio = audio;
this.choices = choices;
this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
return this.answer === choice;
}


function Quiz(questions) {
this.score = 0;
this.questions = questions;
this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
this.score++;
}

this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

I'm trying to make text sound1 into an audio button that can be played as my quiz later

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For audio, you have to make an html element and grab that element by using its id and audio will only play when the user triggers it like when clicked it will not be automatically played.

You can refer [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207043214/http://blog.gingertech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/LCA_MM_AVProc2011/#slide1) for more information.

And please don't copy paste whole code while asking question, paste whatever is required.

Comment: I just need to say, that it is possible to have audio automatically play, as with the audio element, there is such thing as the `.play()` function that can be called to make an audio element play its audio file, so it is possible to have audio to automatically play. Though you are correct, to play audio on the web you do need to have that audio element, here's a link to a greater site to learn more about the [audio tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp).